# Running python script containing relative imports from node file

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, python-module, relative-import

I'm building an app that has a node backend for handling routes but I'm also using some machine learning packages in python. I'm at the point of integrating my python scripts with node so that node can send data to and run my python functions and then get some return data. I am having an issue with importing my defined class from another python file in a different folder into my python file that I'm running from my node file. Before anyone sends me to a related question on relative imports or a help article - I promise you I have read plenty. My problem is that I am running a python child_process from my node file (which is in a different folder than both python files) to execute my python file. I have tried to incorporate a '-m' switch in my child_process spawn command like this:

```
const py = spawn('python', ['-m','../Python/Functions/upload.py', stringifiedData]);
```

but receive no output. My directory is constructed this way :

```
App
|
|-Backend
          |
          |-Node
                server.js
          |-Python
                  | 
                  |-Classes
                           image.py
                  |-Functions
                           upload.py
```

And there are **init**.py files in the Python, Functions, and Classes folders.

In my server.js file (in Node folder)

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const data = '[1,2,3]'

const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data)

const py = spawn('python', ['../Python/Functions/upload.py', stringifiedData]);

py.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: data received from node ${data}`)
})


py.stdout.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`exited with code ${code}`)
})
```

In my image.py file (in Classes folder)

```
class Image():
  ***all my class attributes and class methods***
```

In my upload.py file (run in server.js file through a child_process, python file itself in Functions folder)

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hi from python')
    pdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    import_path = os.path.join(pdir, 'Classes/')
    sys.path.append(import_path)
    os.chdir(import_path)
    
    print(sys.path)

    try:
        from image import Image
 
        i = Image(sys.argv[1])
        print(i.filepath) ##Doing this just to see if my object instantiates 


    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Appending the path to classes folder & changing the directory to this folder has worked for me, but this does not feel like the cleanest way to import, and, overall, I really would like to stop facing the 'no relative import with no known parent package' error. I would be incredibly grateful to never see this output on the command line ever again, as well as the 'No module named X'... And so if anyone out there could offer some advice as to why the code

```
from Classes import image
```

returns 'No module named Classes', and why

```
from .image import Image
```

returns 'attempted relative import with no known parent package' I would really appreciate it.

I could be lazy just insert my class code directly into the function upload.py file, but I have a number of classes and functions, and there will be more code in the function file than there is right now so I would like to keep them separated to their respective folders.

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` switch takes a *module name* not a path. So, supposing the current working directory is `Backend`, then the command should be something like (I never used node):

```
const py = spawn('python', ['-m','Python.Functions.upload', stringifiedData]);
```